# How to Differentiate between kotlin's class inheritence(extends in java) and interface implementation(implements in ) here kotlin uses ( : ) for both?

Tags: java, kotlin

As I'm working in the middle of some kotlin project I got a confusion like whether a child class implements another parent class or else implementing an interface? like I am using some interfaces and classes from a jar which I am not aware a lot about it could someone explain to me a way to solve this since I am new to kotlin.
For Example:
a class definition

```
abstract class Employee (val firstName: String, val lastName: String) {
    abstract fun earnings(): Double
}
```

which is extended by some other class

```
abstract class Employee (val firstName: String, val lastName: String) {
    // ... 

    fun fullName(): String {
        return lastName + " " + firstName;
    }
}
```

Similarly an Interface

```
class Result
class Student 

interface StudentRepository {
    fun getById(id: Long): Student
    fun getResultsById(id: Long): List<Result>
}
```

Interface implementation

```
class StudentLocalDataSource : StudentRepository {
    override fun getResults(id: Long): List<Result> {
       // do implementation
    }

    override fun getById(id: Long): Student {
        // do implementation
    }
}
```

Comment: I think [Sweepers answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51972983/6202869) summarizes it good. Extended classes always contain a `(..)` and interfaces not. Note that you may want to introduce some coding convention if you haven't done so yet, e.g. that you write the extended class in front, followed by all the implemented interfaces (that would basically correspond to what Java forces you to do)... But you don't need to obviously... coding conventions are helpful sometimes and handled too dogmatic other times...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Kotlin, to inherit from a class you have to write its primary constructor, so you will always see the parent class followed by `()`, sometimes with things inside.

Interfaces don't need this. You just write the names of the interfaces and that's it.

So if you see brackets after a name, that's a parent class. Otherwise its an interface.

Comment: what if they use the secondary constructor instead of a primary constructor?

Comment: @CrazyKP What do you mean? All classes have a primary constructor. Can you give me an example of a class that "uses the secondary constructor instead of a primary constructor"?

Comment: Now I get it Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the following example:

```
abstract class Employee(val firstName: String, val lastName: String) {
    abstract fun earnings(): Double
}

interface Hireable {
    fun hire()
}

class HireableEmployee(firstName: String, lastName: String) : Employee(firstName, lastName), Hireable {
    override fun earnings(): Double {
        return 10000.0
    }

    override fun hire() {
        //...
    }
}
```

as you can see the parent class is declared with a constructor invocation `Employee(firstName, lastName)`, the interface declaration `Hireable` has *no* parentheses behind it.

So in Kotlin `extends` corresponds to the `()` behind the name signalling that this is a constructor invocation and therefore the parent class. `implements` has no special syntax, just the name.

For more Information about interfaces see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/interfaces.html

About class hierarchies see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html